# Azure - How to deploy to guest directory via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have created an ARM template that I would like to deploy via Powershell to Azure directory where I am guest - meaning, I have *contributor* access to one particular resource group. How do I do that?

Normally, when using my own subscription, I just go `Login-AzureRMSubscription` and `Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId myidblabla` and then `New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment -name blabla -TemplateFile mypath -ResourceGroupName somenmae`

But how do I target the directories where I am invited? Using `Get-AzureRMSubscriptions`, I can see also where I am guest but I cannot switch to them.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**Edit:** I have tried to `Select-AzureRmSubscription -TenantId` but the reply I get is details about my own subscription including my tenant Id and I still cannot see the resource group that I have access to. *Note* - If I login to the portal, I can easily switch to the directory and see my resource group in the resource group sections and deploy resources to it.

Comment: Do you means you want to use this account to login another AAD?

Comment: Have you try login Azure via new portal? can you find your account with that Azure active directory?

Comment: Jason Ye - Hi Jason, when I login on the portal, I see all the directories including the one where I want to deploy via powershell. I have no problem going to the resource group (where I have access) and for instance create a SQL Database there.

Comment: Please specify tenantid to select-azurermsubscription.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we can use this command to login Azure and change directory.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscripitionID <ID of sub> -TenantId <ID of Azure Tenant>
```

We can actually just specify **the tennant ID** to select the directory, without a subscription ID.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription  -TenantId <ID of Azure Tenant>
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the answer. I should have been more accurate in my question. I have tried this and the command goes through but the reply of the command is showing me again: _Environment:_, _Account:_, _TenantID_, _SubscriptionID_, _SubscriptionName_ and _CurrentStorageAccount_ of my own subscription. Therefore, I try to `Get-AzureRMResourceGroup` to check the only resource groups that I have access to shows up but I get to see yet again resource groups in my own subscription.

Comment: @JS_Diver  TenantID of that directory?

Comment: In the command, I target the TenantID where I want to get to but what I get in the reply, as described in the previous comment, is my own subscription including my own tenantID. The command does not throw any errors or anything.

Comment: I get the tenandID of the target subscription from `Get-AzureRMSubscription` - there I can see the list and I lookup the one where I would like to deploy to.